# Instance class with "Global" settings

Tags: c#, .net

Coming from a scripting background, I've started working with c# and .net. I've created a class that creates a text file notice that a process is complete. I instantiate this class in a console application and call the write process at the end.  What I'm trying to do is keep track through all my other classes when an error or warning has occurred, and reflect that event in the notice.

I've implemented this with public static bools, so that no matter what class is running, when a catch occurs, I can update a bool to true. I get the feeling though that this is wrong, and I don't know enough at this point to find what I should be doing.

Can anyone help?
Code example:

```
namespace Logging
{
public class Notice
{
    public static bool HasWarning { get; set; }
    public static bool HasError { get; set; }

    public string ProcessName {get; set;}


    public enum Status
    {
        [Description("Complete Success")]
        Complete_Success,
        [Description("Complete with Warnings")]
        Complete_With_Warnings,
        [Description("Error Incomplete")]
        Error_Incomplete
    }


    public void EndProcess(Status status)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(string.Format("{0} is Complete!", ProcessName));
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        sb.Append(string.Format("Completion Status: {0}", ToStringEnums(status)));
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        sb.Append(string.Format("Completion Time: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss")));

        File.WriteAllText(string.Format(@"{0}\EndProcess.txt", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()), sb.ToString());
    }
```

This is where I call it:

```
        private static void WriteNotice()
    {
        Notice newNotice = new Notice();
        newNotice.ProcessName = "NCOA";
        if (Notice.HasError == true)
            newNotice.EndProcess(Notice.Status.Error_Incomplete);
        else if (Notice.HasWarning == true)
            newNotice.EndProcess(Notice.Status.Complete_With_Warnings);
        else
            newNotice.EndProcess(Notice.Status.Complete_Success);

    }
```

Comment: If you share a sample of your code we might be able to comment more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a Try Catch statement around your code and trace like following:

```
    try
        {
            //your code goes here

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //write exception detail to output window using .Net Tracing Tools
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

for a more advanced logging mechanism i would recommend using [NLOG](http://nlog-project.org) as following:

```
    static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    try
    {
    //your code
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    logger.Error(ex.Message + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    }
```

Comment: Ok.. That's actually sort of what I'm doing. So instead of writing to bools I create, I write to System Debug, then I can read from it later?

Comment: Writing to System.Diagnostics.Debug gives you ability to Trace application while you're developing(you can see what is being written out in "OUTPUT" window in Visual Studio,but if you want to keep the record of the logs and view it later,i suggest second way(NLOG) which creates a text file and logs every exception in your application(keep in mind it logs only where you had that try-catch block!)

Comment: you can also differentiate Warnings,Errors ,Infos,Debug and Trace logs using following methods:
logger.Error(...
logger.Warn(..
logger.Debug(...
logger.Trace(...

Comment: I see. I am working on a logging system using nlog, but this is actually something a little different. I'm trying to provide info to our existing automation system. It's going to read in this text file when it appears, and if it sees success it will know to continue to the next step. So my try catches do log the exception, they also note in this notice class that something happened.

Comment: I should also note that I realize I'm asking a fairly broad question. I'd appreciate even just a pointer to something I can research..

Comment: do you need to interact with system? if what you want to do in each situation is static,I think implementing your business logic with "Events" is more meaningful,Create 3 Events named "CompleteWithSuccess","CompleteWithError","CompleteWithWarning",and in each of these three events do your things and also create a TabPage or similar one for Printing out logs in each of three situations,

Comment: Ok. I'm going to run with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: your welcome,Please mark "Answer" or vote if this was helpful to you